# What port numbers are used by Mobility Agent installed on On-Premise machine to communicate with Process Server in Azure ASR?

Tags: azure, replication, azure-site-recovery

Which ports the on-premise mobility agent communicates with to transfer the data to process server ? I need to know the ports used on On-Premise server by the Mobility Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses port 443, As Telnet from the process server on port 443.

telnet  443, If the telnet is working there will be No issues from client to the process server connectivity!

9443 port uses for on-promises to Process server - data

Mobility agent send data using port 9443 to PS, Process Server send data to azure Storage using port 443

Comment: you mean to say- Mobility Agent installed on on-premise machine uses port 443 to reach and transfer replication data to Process Server ?